# C# - How do I change the value of a property based on changes to another property (ObservableCollection)?

Tags: c#, observablecollection, propertychanged

How do I change the value of TotalPublicationsRead, when the Read property of a Publication has changed?

```
public class Report
{
   public ObservableCollection<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
   public int TotalPublicationsRead { get; set; }
}

public class Publication : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private bool read;
   public bool Read 
   { 
      get { return this.read; }
      set
      {
         if (this.read!= value)
         {
             this.publications = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Read");
         }
      }
   }

   #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   #endregion

   private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
   {
       if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
       {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
       }
   }           
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to do what I think you are, then I'd change the `TotalPublicationsRead` property and forget about the events. In the code below I just count the items in the list where the `Publication` has been `Read`.

The way you were trying to do it you would have to have an event handler for when the `ObserableCollection` changed. Then you would have to attach an event handler to the `PropertyChanged` event which would increment or decrement the `TotalPublicationsRead` property. I'm sure it would work, but it would be a lot more complicated.

```
public class Report
{
    public List<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
    public int TotalPublicationsRead 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.Publications.Count(p => p.Read); 
        }
    }

}

public class Publication : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool read;
    public bool Read
    {
        get { return this.read; }
        set { this.read = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dependency Property.

Please check details at: 
http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)